# I have tesseract-ocr and hadoop separately. I need to integrate them

Tags: hadoop, tesseract, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-plugins

According to my project of image processing. I need is to integrate hadoop (parallel processor) with tesseract (image processing to txt).

Answer (score 0):

You might find [OSSOCR](https://github.com/artunit/ossocr) useful. It contains a module called python-tesseract for OCR processing. You could use it with Hadoop streaming.

Comment: Hi Tariq, thank you for your wonderful documentation. But, yet i am getting some errors like main_dummy.cpp:7 and publictypes.h errors

Comment: tesseract.i:13: Error: Unable to find 'publictypes.h'

Comment: errors in main_dummy.cpp:ProcessPagesWrapper, tesseract api, tessbaseapi, ProcessPagesFileStream,                          python2.6: can't open file 'tesseract.py'    ImportError: No module named tesseract